# Updating two dependent columns using a single update statement in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have created this table:

```
Create table Vars(A number, B number, C number);
```

Then, I inserted a new row in which only the first column (i.e., `A`) has a value:

```
Insert Into Vars(A) values (2);
```

Now, I want to make an update statement that modify the values of the columns `B` and `C` as follows:

**B = A*A**

**C = B+10**

The problem is that when I execute the following update statement, the value of `B` is updated correctly, but the value of `C` is updated based of the old value of `B`, which is null, not the updated one:

```
Update Vars set B=A*A, C=B+10;
```

Can any one assist me with a way that allows `C` to be calculated based on the updated value of `B` using a single update statement.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can write "update vars set B = A * A, C = (A * A) + 10;

Comment: Actually, the real calculations of the columns are too complicated (what I posted here are just examples). In addition, my table has 10 columns, where each column is updated based on a set of previously updated columns.

Comment: @TeeKea are you using plsql ? in such way its better to write it as plsql block

Comment: To implement this in PL/SQL, I would require to execute update statements many times (equals to the number of rows). My data is too huge, and I need less number of operations.

Comment: @TeeKea I am not sure what you are doing but you can do the calculation first then update your columns.

Comment: you are saying you have a complicated calculation .. how to handle such calculation in the future/

Comment: Another approach could be an UPDATE Trigger...

Comment: Have you considered using virtual columns instead of trying to maintain physical ones?

Comment: Agree with AlexPoole -- if you have column values that are dependent on each other then there is possibly something broken in your model, and the complexity that you are facing is a symptom of that. Isolate the independent variables into actual database columns, and then place the columns that are derived from them into virtual columns. Alternatively, use a view to define the dependent values.

Comment: By the way, the behaviour that you are experiencing is the database protecting you from possible race conditions -- consider "update my_table set A = B * 2, B = A * 2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a sequence of nested sub-queries to evaluate the expressions in the right order. Each inner select transform the column before the outer ones.

The first sub-query (internal) will include ROWID in the column list and the last one (external) will bind the inner ROWID with the UPDATE ROWID. Each intermediate sub-query must include its calculations, the columns required by outer sub-queries and the ROWID generated by the first sub-query.

```
UPDATE VARS V
    SET (B,C) = 
        (SELECT B, B+10 AS C 
          FROM (SELECT A*A AS B, ROWID AS X FROM VARS) 
          WHERE V.ROWID = X
        );
```

Don't worry about the performance of nested sub-queries. No matter how many levels of sub-queries you have, oracle will perform only 1 full table access (the update) and 1 rowid based access (the sub-queries). And the full access is due to the lack of WHERE in your UPDATE.

I have tested it on 11gR2. Oracle optimizer is impressive... it is really scary.

Comment: Well I see what you're doing there, but this could get pretty gnarly with ten columns to update based on each others' values.

Comment: Yes!!!! it is ugly... but efficient. PL/SQL would be prettier, but less efficient (because an update can be parallelized automatically and a PL/SQL block cannot)... But it would be only a little bit gnarly ;-). I have tested really gnarly queries with more than 10000 sub-queries (1 select with 10000 sub-selects), and my little Oracle instance can solve it without any problem.

Comment: Thanks @acesargl, I appreciate your helpful answer, regardless of its complication when applied to my ten columns.

Answer (score 0):

One option to consider, if you do have to do this, is to update an inline view.

If you can define a query of the following form:

```
select *,
       a * a new_b,
       (a * a) + 10 new_c
from   vars
```

... then you can also ...

```
update (
  select *,
         a * a new_b,
         (a * a) + 10 new_c
  from   vars)
set b = new_b,
    c = new_c
```

This also makes the logic very testable as you can run the in-line view as a select to test the values that will be set.

You could probably even have nested inline views ...

```
select
  v.*,
  new_b + 10 new_c
from (
  select
    *,
    a * a new_b
  from
    vars) v
```

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't execute this kind of queries: "select *, a from vars".
I get this error: "ORA-00923 FROM keyword not found where expected".